# How can I put restrictions on a user?

Tags: debian-lenny

I want to give a developer access to my VPS, but only to 1 directory. I don't want him to be able to do anything other than create, edit, and delete files. I just want to keep my server safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you just need to make a chrooted FTP account for them. There are many FTP servers you can choice from, but I can recommend vsftpd.